# JavaScript events and "srcElement"

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

I am having a specific problem with the JS event "onclick" and how it works in a very specific case. I have a set of nested DIVs that looks like this (somewhat):

In code:

```
<div id="A" ...> 
    <div id="B" ...> </div> 
    <div id="C" ...> </div> 
</div>
```

The exact position of the DIVs are arbitrary, just know that there are nested DIVs.

DIV A has an onclick event attached to it.

When a user clicks on the divs I intend for the srcElement to without exception be div A.
Or maybe I'm just not using the right property.

Basically I want to be able to get the name of the div whose onclick event was called.
from inside the onclick function

Comment: Are you using any JS library like jQuery?

Comment: No. I would prefer to have solutions that do not require any external API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `onclick` is on `A`, then `this` in the handler will represent that element.

```
document.getElementById('A').onclick = function() {
    // "this" is the A element
    alert( this.id );  // alert the ID attribute of the element
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `div`s don't have a name per se in HTML4. They can have a title, though. In JS without a framework, you could get the title this way:

```
document.getElementById("A").onclick = function() {
    alert(this.title);
}
```

This appears to work well in my tests.

Comment: So you suggest I name my divs with the title propery?

Comment: That's hard to answer since I don't know what you're using the "name" for. You could just as well use the id, but in the example given it was a little weird to find an element by its id and then ask Javascript what its id was.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Patrick's solution provided you attach the listener as a property of the element.

If you use IE's attachEvent method, it will not work as it doesn't set the listener's this keyword to the element when called. There are numerous work arounds for that. IE 9 introduces addEventListener, hopefully with the this keyword set per other browsers.

Event.srcElement is the IE equivalent of the W3C Event.target property and is the element on which the event originally occured. For bubbling events, to find the element whose handler called the listener, it is best to set the listener's this keyword in the call so that you can refer to the associated element as 'this'.

Note also that there is no consistency in the order that listeners will be called when attached using attachEvent or addEventListener (HTML5 tries to fix that, but it isn't widely implemented yet and will not fix attachEvent's order anyway).

It is usually best to keep event registration as simple as possible. Once you have a complex system, you'll likelyl need your own event registration and calling system to avoid the various browser peculiarities (there are a number of those).

-- 
Rob